# What's the best way to predict the time series when we have an irregular variation

Tags: python, time-series, prediction, forecasting, arima

I'm trying to predict the headcount based on the 36 months data.
But during the covid, it caused the irregular variation from Jan 2020 to Dec 2022.
I understand that if we have more data points, it might be easier.
I used ARIMA and ETS and predict headcount for 12 months and it is showing very different from the actual data.

Can you help to advise why it so different?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing
from itertools import product
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Load data
df = pd.read_csv('data2.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date')

# Split data into train and test sets
train = df.iloc[:-12]
test = df.iloc[-12:]

# Define parameter grids for ARIMA and ETS models
arima_params = [(p,d,q) for p in range(3) for d in range(3) for q in range(3)]
ets_params = [{'trend': t, 'seasonal': s, 'seasonal_periods': 12} for t in ['add', 'mul'] for s in ['add', 'mul']]

# Define function to fit ARIMA and ETS models
def fit_models(train, arima_params, ets_params):
    best_rmse = np.inf
    best_arima = None
    best_ets = None
    for arima_order in arima_params:
        for ets_param in ets_params:
            # Fit ARIMA model
            arima = SARIMAX(train, order=arima_order)
            arima_fit = arima.fit(disp=False)
            # Fit ETS model
            ets = ExponentialSmoothing(train, trend=ets_param['trend'], seasonal=ets_param['seasonal'], seasonal_periods=ets_param['seasonal_periods'])
            ets_fit = ets.fit()
            # Combine ARIMA and ETS predictions
            pred = arima_fit.forecast(steps=12) + ets_fit.forecast(steps=12)
            # Compute RMSE
            rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test, pred))
            # Update best models if RMSE is lower
            if rmse < best_rmse:
                best_rmse = rmse
                best_arima = arima_fit
                best_ets = ets_fit
    return best_arima, best_ets

# Fit ARIMA and ETS models
arima_model, ets_model = fit_models(train, arima_params, ets_params)

# Combine ARIMA and ETS predictions
pred = arima_model.forecast(steps=12) + ets_model.forecast(steps=12)
```

Comment: What are the p, d and q values for the SARIMAX model? I assume the model would find that the series is non-stationary and has a decreasing trend so it continues to model it so. I'd suggest taking a dataset for a larger timeframe and trying again.